# Jackson Use Setter While Deserialization

Tags: java, jackson

I am trying to use my custom setter function while deserialize json with using jackson in Java. My goal is to validate fields such as if field length is more than 5, crop last 2 char etc. Or if a field which expected as integer comes with a string, try to convert etc.

Here is my logic.

```
public class Channel {
    private String depositWithdrawalFlag;
    private String paymentOrderFlag;
    .
    .
    //MORE FIELDS

    @JsonCreator
    public Channel(@JsonProperty(value = "depositWithdrawalFlag", required = true) String depositWithdrawalFlag,
                   @JsonProperty("paymentOrderFlag") String paymentOrderFlag,
                   .
                   .
                   //MORE PROPERTIES


    {
        this.depositWithdrawalFlag = depositWithdrawalFlag;
        this.paymentOrderFlag = paymentOrderFlag;
        .
        .
        //MORE INITIALIZATIONS
    }
```

## EXAMPLE SETTER

```
@JsonSetter()
public void setDepositWithdrawalFlag(String depositWithdrawalFlag) {
    System.out.println("Deneme");
    switch (depositWithdrawalFlag.toUpperCase()) {
        case "D":
        case "Q":
            this.depositWithdrawalFlag = depositWithdrawalFlag;
            break;
        default:
            this.depositWithdrawalFlag = "D";
            break;
    }
}
```

If i try to remove the constructor and add `JsonProperty` on top of the private fields, required logic is not working but setters work this time.

How can i handle this situation? Thanks

Comment: Delegate to your setter from the constructor?

Comment: Is it going to be good solution? I thought there might be a better solution